# Does kill-new take some time to put a string on the system clipboard?

Tags: microsoft-windows, kill-ring, clipboard

I have an emacs function which calls `kill-new` to put a string onto the Windows system clipboard and then immediately invokes an external script to paste that string from the clipboard to an other application.

Sometimes the string was not yet copied to the clipboard when the pasting was done, so I had to add a little delay before invoking the external script.

Is adding a string to the Windows clipboard via `kill-new` an async operation? I thought it was done immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> Is adding a string to the Windows clipboard via `kill-new` an async operation?

I don't use Windows, but *in general* `kill-new` simply calls `(funcall interprogram-cut-function string)` and that configured function might do *anything*, so it could be synchronous or asynchronous.

For the *default* behaviour, I think you'll be looking at `C-h f w32-set-clipboard-data` (and AFAICS *that* would be called synchronously, but I can't say anything beyond that).

You can likely confirm that much by setting `debug-on-entry` for `w32-set-clipboard-data`.